# Magnolia CMS (5.3) - User export to CSV or convert JCR XML to CSV

Tags: wordpress, export-to-csv, jcr, magnolia

Does anybody knows a way how I can export all users from Magnolia CMS 5.3 to a simple .csv file or how to convert the exportable JCR XML (or YAML) file into a .csv file?

I need to migrate the users from Magnolia CMS to WordPress, but can't handle the JCR XML file. I'm trying to get it compatible to WP ALL IMPORT.

All ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Magnolia you can export all users as xml (JCR XML), by going to `Tools > JCR Tools > Exporter tab` in Magnolia, select `users` workspace and `/` path. The resulted xml can easily be transformed to csv format by writing a simple [XSLT transformer](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp). 
You can find more detailed information about exporting data in Magnolia in their [official documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Importing+and+exporting+JCR+data+for+bootstrapping).